# RUBY - Correct way of doing array of hashes inside of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

i need to do an array of hashes inside of a hash, something like this:

```
merit_hash => {
    students => [
    {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        subjects => [
            {
                "id": id,
                "grade": grade
            },
            {
                "id": id,
                "grade": grade
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        subjects => [
            {
                "id": id,
                "grade": grade
            },
            {
                "id": id,
                "grade": grade
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Right now, i just have the array of student hashes, but i dont exactly know how to put the subject array inside of it, im doing this:

```
merit = {}
merit["students"] = []

students.each do |students|
    student_subjects = Array.new
    merit["students"].push(    
      {
        "id" => students.id,
        "name" => students.name.to_s
        selected_batch_subjects.each do |subjects|
            grade = FinalGrades.where(batch_subject_id:subjects.id, period_id: period.id, student_id: student.id).first.value
            student_subjects.push(
                {
             "id" => subjects.id,
             "grade"=> grade
                }
            )
        end 
      }
    )
end
```

but throws this error

> unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end

when i try to close the student hash... what can i do to make this work? or, whats the best way of implementing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
merit = {}
merit["students"] = []
students.each do |student|
  student_information = {"id" => student.id, "name" => student.name.to_s}
  student_subjects = []
  selected_batch_subjects.each do |subjects|
    grade = FinalGrades.where(batch_subject_id:subjects.id, period_id: period.id, student_id: student.id).first.value
    student_subjects.push({"id" => subjects.id, "grade" => grade})
  end
  student_information[:subjects] = student_subjects
  merit["students"].push(student_information)
end
```

The important part is adding each student's subjects to the already existing hash.

Comment: Perfect! this is what i was looking for. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Your iterations are not very clear to me but for current loop and array push you could do like this:

```
merit = {}
merit["students"] = []

students.each do |students|
    student_subjects = []
    merit["students"] << {
        "id" => students.id,
        "name" => students.name.to_s
    }
    selected_batch_subjects.each do |subjects|
    grade = FinalGrades.where(batch_subject_id:subjects.id, period_id:   period.id, student_id: student.id).first.value
        student_subjects << {"id" => subjects.id,"grade"=> grade}  
    end
end
```